# /dev/ttyACM0: permission denied on openSUSE

Tags: linux, arduino, serial-port, arduino-ide, opensuse

I am trying to use an "Arduboy," based on the Arduino Leonardo, with the Arduino IDE. I cannot upload the example code, however, because of the following error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Before you mark this as a duplicate, here are all of the things I have tried

- Adding myself to the `dialout` group that `/dev/ttyACM0` can be modified by
- Running `chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0` every time I plug in the board
- Making this udev rule: `KERNEL=="ttyACM0", MODE="0666"`

None of these things worked. What *did* work was running it with `xdg-su` like so: `xdg-su -c ./arduino`. However, I think it's not the best idea to run the thing as root every time. Is there *anything* I can do?

I am running openSUSE Tumbleweed.

Comment: did you log-out and log-in after adding user to the group?

Comment: @Juraj totally, even did a reboot after the udev thing

Comment: What are the responses to the following commands: (a) `ls -l /dev/ttyACM*` and (b) `groups` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino Leonardo based boards interrupt the communication with ttyACM* for a short moment (like logging in and out) during an upload. For some reason, the permissions change during this process. See the output of a repeated `ls -l --full-time /dev/ttyACM0` during a failed upload:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 2019-08-11 17:28:31.974025089 +0200 /dev/ttyACM0
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyACM0': No such file or directory
crw------- 1 root root 166, 0 2019-08-11 17:42:15.523439213 +0200 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 2019-08-11 17:42:16.083442857 +0200 /dev/ttyACM0
```

I also use Tumbleweed. The only workaround that I currently know is to start the Arduino IDE as root.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your arduino's program directory. Open terminal in the directory. Then type `./arduino-linux-setup.sh $USER`. After that reboot. You are able to upload code onto your arduino.